# How to Create the Left Join by using the group by data

Tags: c#, linq, left-join

I have three Table One is "`Allowance` " ,"`Balance`" and "`TimeoffRequests`" in these three table common columns are `EmployeeId` and `TimeoffTypeId`, Now i need to get the requested hours of one leave type by grouping thier `timeoffTypeId` and `EmployeeId` from the table "`TimeoffRequests`" , and got the "`TimeOffHours`". for the i wrote the code like

```
var query = (from tr in TimeOffRequests
             where tr.EmployeeID == 9
             group tr by new { tr.EmployeeID, tr.TimeOffTypeID } into res
             select new
             {
                 EmployeeID = res.Key.EmployeeID,
                 TimeOffTypeID = res.Key.TimeOffTypeID,
                 TotalHours = res.Sum(x => x.TimeOffHours)
             }).AsEnumerable();
```

[image]

Now I need to join these results with the first table and have to get the all the employees, and `timeoffTypes` from the `UserAllowance` and corresponding **`TimeoffHours`** from the grouped table.    for getting left joined query i wrote like below.

```
var requestResult = (from UA in UserAllowances
                     join UB in UserBalances on UA.EmployeeID equals UB.EmployeeID
                     where UA.TimeOffTypeID == UB.TimeOffTypeID && UA.EmployeeID == 9
                      && UA.TimeOffType.IsDeductableType == true      // LeftJoin

                     join rest in query on UA.EmployeeID equals rest.EmployeeID into penidngRequst
                     from penReq in penidngRequst.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where penReq.TimeOffTypeID == UA.TimeOffTypeID

                     select new EmployeeTimeOffBalanceModel
                     {
                         TimeOffTypeID = UA.TimeOffTypeID != null ? UA.TimeOffTypeID : 0,
                         YearlyAllowanceHrs = (UA.YearlyAllowanceHrs != null) ? UA.YearlyAllowanceHrs : 0,
                         BalanceHours = UB.BalanceHrs != null ? UB.BalanceHrs : 0,
                         PendingHours = (decimal)((penReq != null) ? (penReq.TotalHours) : 0),
                         EmployeeID = UA != null ? UA.EmployeeID : 0,


                     }).ToList().Distinct();
```

It is giving only **`timeOFfType`** containing in grouped data,even though I wrote `leftjoin` for the query using the "into" and `DefaultIfEmpty()` keywords. the results becomes as like:

[image]

and by using the "linqPad" editor i found that it is applying the `Cross` or `Outer Join` instead of "left join" what will be the reason.

If I remove  this line of code **`" where penReq.TimeOffTypeID
== UA.TimeOffTypeID"`** this showing all the `timeoffTypes` with `cross join` with repeatation like

[image: with repeated timeoffhours]

How can I achieve left join with tables with Grouped data and showing null values if `timeofftypes` didn't having the any request?

Comment: UserAllowance table had 6 timeoffType records with that employee id but it is showing only 3 timeoffTypes records after join with grouped data.

Comment: Separate your 2nd linq into multiple parts. Before your left outer join comment, put that part of the query into a variable and could you show the results from that part of the query?

Comment: Also, anytime a linq query is causing unexpected results, break it up into parts and use the debugger to inspect the various parts.

Comment: Hi Rick,i tried to place the first join into one variable and then joined that variable with the Grouped data as left join but it showing the same result.

Comment: Please update your question to show the results from the first join. Thanks

Comment: @VGSNaidu please post a SQL query that recreates the table and some data - this will help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to move the where clause into the the on equals clause as shown below

```
join rest in query on new { UA.EmployeeID, UA.TimeOffTypeID } equals new { rest.EmployeeID, rest.TimeOffTypeID } into penidngRequst
from penReq in penidngRequst.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change

```
where penReq.TimeOffTypeID == UA.TimeOffTypeID
```

to

```
where penReq == null || penReq.TimeOffTypeID == UA.TimeOffTypeID
```